# Cliff's Delta in R?

Tags: r, effect-size

I've been playing around in R quite a bit and am looking for a way to compute Cliff's Delta on a set of items from a personality questionnaire between two groups of students (control and experimental)

I'm wondering what I would need to do to set up the data. For instance, would it be just a matter of having a set of questions across columns for each group (e.g., Q1_control, Q1_experiment, and so on), and having the id's in the first row, or is it slightly more involved?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

D.

Comment: Check the `dmes()` function in the orddom package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/orddom/index.html

Comment: In general in R you are better off having everything in long format. That is one column per variable, and your variables are e.g. Subject, Group, Question, Response.  It is then easy to subset the data as needed to compare e.g. each question between groups.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments everyone! Currently looking into the dmes function

@user162986, I've got my data split out into two data sets for each group, however they're unequal sample sizes. What function would I use that would adjust for that?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no adjustment necessary when using `dmes()`. The formula in the manual does not assume the same sample size for both groups.

Comment: I have used the effsize package to calculate Cliff's delta and Vargha and Delaney's A.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [orddom package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/orddom/index.html). There are two relevant functions, `dmes()` and `orddom()`. The `orddom()` function will compute two Cliff's delta values, one using only the ordinal information in the data, and the other treating the data as interval. Different sample sizes in both groups are acceptable. Separate columns of data in one `data.frame()` are preferable for orddom. But it is probably best to treat each column as an individual vector when using the orddom package.

Comment: Thanks again @user162986. I apologize, I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to the more nuanced functions, the orddom function works well, but when I try running the dmes I'm getting the error: 

Error in Ops.data.frame(y[j], x[i]) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Just wondering what that might signify.

Comment: It's because your columns have different lengths, related to my suggestion of using vectors. But if orddom works fine, then I suggest you stick with it.

Comment: Copy that. Thanks so much for all the help @user162986. Greatly appreciated!